# Node.JS MySQL insert without characters escaping

Tags: mysql, node.js, insert

How to do MySQL insert in Node.JS without characters escaping?

```
var row = {
  col1: 'value1',
  col2: 'value2',
  foreignKeyCol: "(SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE someCol = 'someVal')"
};

cn.query("INSERT INTO table2 SET ?", row, function (err,result) {
//
});
```

Sure, this final query will not work because it's trying to insert string instead of select query result:

```
INSERT INTO table2 
SET `col1` = 'value1',
    `col2` = 'value2',
    `foreignKeyCol` = "(SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE someCol = 'someVal')"
```

Comment: This is not good solution in my opinion:

Comment: cn.query("INSERT INTO table2 (col1, col2, foreignKeyCol) VALUES ('"+row.col1+"', '+row.col2+"', (SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE someCol = 'someVal'))", row, function (err,result) {
//
});